# How to update a deserialized object in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I want to update an object after it has been deserialized then re-serialize said object back into its file.

The object I want to update might also contain a data structure that contains other instances of another class. I have made those classes implement `Serializable`.

How can I update the instance of my object without overriding any other instances stored within the same txt file? I Basically want to create methods similar to updating,deleting, inserting in an actual database.

I can't use a RDMS, as I must store my objects this way.

The code below is what I've come up with at the moment.

```
public void updateapplications() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    Applicant applicant;
    File dir = new File("./Users/");
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
    if (directoryListing != null) {
        for (File child : directoryListing) {
            // Do something with child
            // think child is filename?
            if (this.user.getName() == child.getName()){
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(child);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                Object obj = ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                applicant = (Applicant) obj;
                //How can i update the instance of my object withought overiding any other instances
                // stored within the same txt file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(child.getName());
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(obj);
                fos.close();
                break;
            }

}
```

Comment: If your record can increase in size as a result of the update, then it is not going to fit back into where it came from.  You have 3 choices: either 1) copy the entire file with your new record, 2) read all the remainder of the file, then write your new record followed by that remainder, or 3) append your new record, and flag the original position as “deleted” (and periodically purge the deleted records).  Now you know why databases became so popular :)

Comment: 1) The result of an `ObjectOutputStream` is a binary data stream. As such, the result is not a *text* file. 2) Since you just read the object from a file, the file only contains the one object and its nested objects, which will all be re-written on out, so what other object instances are you referring to?

Comment: Understand that object serialisation is NOT intended for the long term storage of objects and is meant to be used more as a communication mechanism, sharing objects across memory boundaries/inter process communication and wire transmissions

Comment: @Andreas for example lets say the object i want to serialize is an instance of the "User class", which also contains an instance variable that stores a list of instances from an "application class". When i deserialize the instance of the "user class" would i have to deserialize the instance in the user class that stores the list of "application instances" as well. How would I proceed in accessing the data stored in this variable?

Comment: Can you just deserialize the object inside the file and store it in a list, and make the necessary operations on the deserialized object and when you're about to close your program just serialize it again?

Comment: 1. Serialized objects are not text and should not be stored in files with the.txt extension. They are binary. 2. Serialized streams are not random access, they are sequential. You can't do this.

Comment: By default, when you serialize an object, all referenced objects are serialized too, and objects they reference, and objects they reference, until the entire object network has been serialized. You can use it to store *all* the data when your program ends, then reload the data when program is restarted, but versioning is an issue, as the program gets upgraded. Can be done, but it's not easy, and you should consider storing the data in a different format, e.g. XML or JSON. If you want to only load some of the data, not all of it, you should probably use a database, RDBMS or NOSQL.

Comment: @Mark  sorry i meant ser files.

Comment: @user207421 sorry i meant ser files